# what is the canonical way to start a daemon in rhel/centos-6 init script?

Tags: centos, rhel, init-script, init

I found lots of good documentation for ubuntu's start-stop-daemon and there is a man page for a binary `daemon`.

But from what I can tell the canonical way to start a daemon in a rhel/centos script is to source `/etc/init.d/functions` then use the `daemon()` function. But I can't find any good examples or documentation.

**What is the canonical way to start a daemon in rhel/centos-6 init script?**

my first attempt was:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /etc/init.d/functions
daemon --user USER nohup /path/to/your/binary arg1 arg2 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: @Christopher I updated the question (not `systemd`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation and example you are looking for is located at `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysvinitfiles` on CentOS/RHEL. Here is the documentation for the `daemon` function specifically:

> daemon  [ --check  ] [ --user ] 
>           [+/-nicelevel] program [arguments] [&]
>
> ```
>     Starts a daemon, if it is not already running.  Does
>     other useful things like keeping the daemon from dumping
>     core if it terminates unexpectedly.
>
>     --check <name>:
>        Check that <name> is running, as opposed to simply the
>        first argument passed to daemon().
>     --user <username>:
>        Run command as user <username>
> ```

With CentOS/RHEL 6, you also have the option of using an upstart job file instead of writing a sysv init script.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for: 1. real documentation 2. guidance on whether I should add an `&` at the end of the line or not (there are other similar daemon commands that do the `&` background operation for you)